# rewriting multiple urls for different paths

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

how can I achieve re-writing multiple urls at the same time. I know I can rewrite one url at the time, but not sure what the format will look like if multiple urls...

let's say I have these files and want to re-write them:

```
https://www.mydomain.com/log/member/1

https://www.mydomain.com/folder2/appl/custom/folder3

https://www.mydomain.com/log/folder3/folder2/name
```

To

```
https://www.mydomain.com/log/1

https://www.mydomain.com/folder2/folder3

https://www.mydomain.com/log/name
```

now how does it work if I include the rules in the web root .htaccess or the individual .htaccess? is it the same format?

please let me know.

All comments are appreciated.

**Update**

Thanks @ThinkingMonkey. The code worked well. There was a little thing missing, which is the php handler since I use index.php.

the missing line is: `DirectoryIndex index.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `folder` rewrites are not generic. You will have to have individual rewrites. Similar to the one mentioned in my previous ans. You have to add them into `web root`'s `.htaccess`.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(?:\.\w+|/)$
RewriteRule (.*) /$1/ [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/log)(/\d+)$
RewriteRule ^ %1/member%2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/log)(/\w+)$
RewriteRule ^ %1/folder3/folder2%2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(folder2)/(folder3)
RewriteRule ^ %1/appl/custom/%2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/folder2)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /accout/log/folder1/$1 [L]



RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/log)/member(/d+)$
RewriteRule ^ %1%2 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/log)/folder3/folder2(/name)$
RewriteRule ^ %1%2 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/folder2)/appl/custom(/folder3)
RewriteRule ^ %1%2 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/accout/log/folder1/folder2
RewriteRule accout/log/folder1/(folder2)(/(.*))?$ $1$2 [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Thinking. I will try it and let you know. I tried your answer in the other post, but it didn't work. any idea why?? appreciated.

Comment: @Digitalsite What errors it it give? I am asking because I tested it before posting.

Comment: when I place the code in .htaccess in the web root and try the links, they show up without wwwm, but only https. Also look like it doesn't recognize .php format, but only html.

Comment: @Digitalsite have you set the `AddHandler` for PHP files? ans what other rewrite rules do you have?

Comment: I don't know how to add a handle for php. I have some other rules like redirecting the home page to https instead of http. also another rule to force all links to have www. if you want me to post the code, I have no problem with that. Thanks

Comment: @Digitalsite make sure that your `http` to `https` rewrite does a redirection to `www.domainname.com`. Lets continue this discussion in chat.

Comment: @Digitalsite what is happening when you access a `.php` page?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8119/discussion-between-digital-site-and-thinkingmonkey)